# Efficient proximity calculation for sibling objects?

Tags: objective-c, oop

So I have a collection of Agent objects that exist within a World object.

These Agents need to inspect their siblings and depending on their proximity take certain actions.

Current I do the following.

1. The World decides it's time to update state, it does so and then loops through and passes this message on to each Agent for it to also update state.
2. Each Agent in turn then asks the World for the array of Agents and proceeds to loop through them checking proximity of each one to see which if any it needs to act on.

Is there a better way of doing this? I can see one glaring inefficiency being that every proximity is calculated twice, once from each end.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on the number of agents, you may find it better to instead have each agent broadcast its location whenever it changes via `NSNotificationCenter`.  Each agent will then subscribe to this notification and each will be aware in ***real time*** of every location change of every agent and act accordingly.  This method could open up possibilities for you later, for example, if you wish to check if any agent performs some action like:  *"Agent throws ball; agent receives notification and decides to catch ball"*.

So, your agent implementation might look something like this:

```
-(id)init
{
   ...
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(agentLocationDidChange:) name:NOTIF_AGENT_LOCATION_DID_CHANGE object:nil];

   return self;
}
-(void)agentLocationDidChange:(NSNotification *)notif
{
   Agent *agent = [notif object];
   if ([agent isEqual:self])
       return; //We don't care about our own actions

   if ([self isAgentCloseProximity:agent])
   { 
      //Do something
   }
}
-(BOOL)isAgentCloseProximity:(Agent *)agent
{
    CGFloat xDistance = agent.location.x - self.location.x;
    CGFloat yDistance = agent.location.y - self.location.y;
    CGFloat distance = sqrt((xDistance*xDistance)+(yDistance*yDistance));
    CGFloat threshold = ...; //<- this could be some constant that you define
    BOOL isClose = distance < threshold;
    return isClose;
}
-(void)changeLocation:(CGPoint)location
{
     //some logic to change my location
     ...
     [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:NOTIF_AGENT_LOCATION_DID_CHANGE object:self];
}
```

Comment: This makes sense with intermittent updates, but with every Agent updating state with every tick there are going to be notifications flying everywhere. Can't Agents infer that every other Agent is updated since they themselves are updating?

Comment: That depends solely on your app.  Inferring anything isn't a good idea unless you know every one of your agents is to be moved together.  Do your agents move independently or do they all move together, à la Space Invaders?  There are notifications flying everywhere anyway, you just don't see them or observe them (nor do you even notice them).

Comment: They move simultaneously with each tick of time. So each one looks at all the others and based on what he sees figures out his next move.